# How to get Elements to Follow Cursor After Scrolling Vertically in Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a HTML element to follow my mouse cursor as I scroll down a web page, but when I scroll down, the HTML element gets 'misaligned'. I get the impression this is due to my cursor's new x,y positions but I don't know how to proceed from here.

**The Code - HTML:**

> ```
>       <div id="mouseOverElement">
>                  <h3 id="mouseOverText">
>                             test text
>                  </h3>
>       </div>
> ```

**The Code - JavaScript:**

> ```
>        let root = document.documentElement;
>
>        root.addEventListener("mousemove", e =>
>        {
>                  root.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', e.clientX + "px");
>                  root.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', e.clientY + "px");
>        });
> ```

**The Code - CSS:**

> ```
>         #mouseOverElement 
>         {
>                     width: 200px;
>                     height: 100px;
>                     background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
>                     position: absolute;
>                     color: white;
>                     left: var(--mouse-x);
>                     top: var(--mouse-y);
>         }
> ```

Comment: Are you looking for pageX, pageY rather than clientX, clientY (which give the position in terms of the viewport not the whole thing).

Answer (score 0):

You have to account for the scroll y position. `window.scrollY + e.clientY` does the trick.

```js
let root = document.documentElement;

root.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  root.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', e.clientX + "px");
  root.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', window.scrollY + e.clientY + "px");
});
```

```css
#mouseOverElement {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: var(--mouse-x);
  top: var(--mouse-y);
}

html, body{
  height:200%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mouseOverElement">
  <h3 id="mouseOverText">
    test text
  </h3>
</div>
```

To update the position while scrolling we can also add an event listener for `scroll`:

```js
let root = document.documentElement;

root.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  root.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', e.clientX + "px");
  root.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', window.scrollY + e.clientY + "px");
});
document.body.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
  root.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', e.clientX + "px");
  root.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', window.scrollY + e.clientY + "px");
});
```

```css
#mouseOverElement {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: var(--mouse-x);
  top: var(--mouse-y);
}

html, body{
  height:200%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mouseOverElement">
  <h3 id="mouseOverText">
    test text
  </h3>
</div>
```